# How to Scale an image or resize to avoid out of memory error?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I'm new to development and I've been trying to make a simple game for a while now, and I'm not able to make it work properly because it keeps getting out of memory issues on most devices.

I reduced the image sizes as much as I can and my biggest image is 117kB.

My images are stored in a single drawable folder. I don't think using xxhdpi or xhdpi separately is required for my images. so in the manifest i have mentioned all the support screen sizes code.

I tried the following thing in my manifest but it didn't help.

```
    android:largeheap = "true"
    android:noHistory = "true" (for every activity so that it doesn't stack up over each other)
```

I have about 50 activities ( all with separate formats so can't make just 1 activity) and these activities are generated randomly from a common application class.

My Q1.java

```
    public class Q1 extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    int score;
     MediaPlayer player;
   TextView scored;
   LinearLayout imageview3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_q1);


    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    imageview3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scoreview);
    Intent mintent = getIntent();
    score = mintent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));


    TextView scrolltext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltext);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/panicStricken.ttf");

    scrolltext.setTypeface(custom_font);

}

public void button(View view) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(Q1.this, R.raw.correct);

    player.setVolume(50,50);
    player.start();

    Class activityToShow = ActivityList.getInstance().getRandomActivity();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,activityToShow );
    intent.putExtra("score", score);

    startActivity(intent);


}

public void fedex(View view) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(Q1.this, R.raw.wrong);

    player.setVolume(50,50);
    player.start();
    score = score - 1;
    scored.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    if (score == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {



    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainMenu.class);

    startActivity(intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

my layout_q1 xml

```
      <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scoreview"
    android:background="@drawable/pic"
    android:onClick="pic"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView11" />
```

I know there's an article about [loading large bitmaps efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) 
but I'm not that great at programming and it's still a little tricky for me to take code and apply it into my own app.

Can someone help me with the best way I can go about this?.

I don't think I can reduce the size of the images further. The best I could do maybe is keep all the image sizes to an average of 50kB, that's about 50 images of 50kB.

When android loads up all these images together will my size reduction be enough to stop this out of memory nightmare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem happens on image resizing. Resizing image just a few time/or just once is not really alarming but when you do it often you will surely hit the OOM error in no time. The strategy to overcome this issue is through caching. When you cached the image it will guarantee you that you will only need to resize things at fewer times/steps.

Here is a visual Usecase through Flow chart.
[image]

The Flowchart above shows the proper way of handling this case. We have an abstracted `Cache` that stores the previous image (Note: The cache is your personal preference and it can be any like : Memory Cache, Database Cache or File Cache. Feel free also to read about [LRU cache - Least Recently used Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) ).

Comment: Hey...ur method seems like a good option but my question was about how to apply it in my code as I'm a beginner...if you could be kind enough to let me know how I can apply it to an activity ... pretty please?

Comment: If you can follow the algorithm I suggested, it would be easier for you next time. Basically the whole idea of my solution is to cached the resized image so that next time if you need that image again you will no longer need to resize it because you have a copy of that resized image in your cache.(Resizing is one of the culprit of OOM) BTW I am also a new to Android. If you have a personal question you can find my contact at my profile. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid out of memory error use BitmapFactory.Options class to reduce image pixel size and then compress the image as shown below

```
       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.inSampleSize = 3;
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, stream);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: There is also [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) of how to efficiently load images/thumbnails without degrading the quality to much.  Might worth a try.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to apply that bitmap factory code to my game....as in how do I assign an image to be scalable in each activity?